# Number of similarity classes of matrices $A$ in $M_6(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying $(A-2I)^3=0.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, jordan-normal-form, characteristic-polynomial

**Find the number of similarity classes of matrices $A$ in $M_6(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying $(A-2I)^3=0.$**

If $(A-2I)^3$ then the characteristic polynomial is $p_A(x)=(x-2)^6$ and we have 3 posibilities for $m_A(x)$, wich are: $(x-2)^3, (x-2)^2, (x-2)$.

We have then:

1. if $p_A(x)=(x-2)^6$ and $m_A=(x-2)^3$ then

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 &  &  &  &  &  \\
1 & 2 &  &  &  &  \\
 & 1 & 2 &  &  &  \\
 &  &  & 2 &  &  \\
 &  &  & 1 & 2 &  \\
 &  &  &  & 1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 &  &  &  &  &  \\
1 & 2 &  &  &  &  \\
 & 1 & 2 &  &  &  \\
 &  &  & 2 &  &  \\
 &  &  & 1 & 2 &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 &  &  &  &  &  \\
1 & 2 &  &  &  &  \\
 & 1 & 2 &  &  &  \\
 &  &  & 2 &  &  \\
 &  &  &  & 2 &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

2. if $p_A(x)=(x-2)^6$ and $m_A=(x-2)^2$ then

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 &  &  &  &  &  \\
1 & 2 &  &  &  &  \\
 &  & 2 &  &  &  \\
 &  & 1 & 2 &  &  \\
 &  &  &  & 2 &  \\
 &  &  &  & 1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 &  &  &  &  &  \\
1 & 2 &  &  &  &  \\
 &  & 2 &  &  &  \\
 &  & 1 & 2 &  &  \\
 &  &  &  & 2 &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2 &  &  &  &  &  \\
1 & 2 &  &  &  &  \\
 &  & 2 &  &  &  \\
 &  &  & 2 &  &  \\
 &  &  &  & 2 &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

3. if $p_A(x)=(x-2)^6$ and $m_A=(x-2)$ then

\begin{bmatrix}
2 &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & 2 &  &  &  &  \\
 &  & 2 &  &  &  \\
 &  &  & 2 &  &  \\
 &  &  &  & 2 &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Is this correct?

Comment: I must assume that you want the number of similarity classes, because the number of matrices themselves is $\mathfrak c$. The matrix in case (1) has $m_A=(x-2)^2$. The first matrix in case (2) has $m_A=(x-2)^3$. The second and third matrices in case (2) are similar and they have $m_A=(x-2)^4$. The fourth and fifth matrices in case (2) are similar and they have $m_A=(x-2)^5$. The matrix in case (3) has $m_A=(x-2)^6$.

Comment: Some matrices in your post do not satisfy $(A-2I)^3=0,$ for example the last one.

Comment: @user402543 Please leave a comment to verify that the revisions made to your question are correct, or [edit] your post to reflect what you actually mean

Comment: @user402543 As the first two comments indicate, the answer to your question (assuming that the problem statement was correctly interpreted) is no: your answer is not correct.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I already corrected my post, please see if Im wrong, thanks!

Comment: @user402543 Yes, your latest answer is correct